# Snapping in Geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas, snapping

I want to perform snapping in all the lines of a shapefile that don't connect to the nearest other lines. It would be okay to have a tolerance of 0.5 meters. So between 0.5 it should connect to the near lines. I have done this:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import snap
s=gpd.read_file(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\ag_eus')
result=snap(s,s,0.5)
```

It gives:

```
AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute '_geom'
```

Some more info about the shapefile:

```
s.columns

Index(['Layer', 'SubClasses', 'ExtendedEn', 'Linetype', 'EntityHand', 'Text',
       'geometry'],
      dtype='object')
```

---

Update from the answer that provided:

```
for index, row in s.iterrows():
    tmp_gdf = s.copy()
    tmp_gdf['distance'] = tmp_gdf.distance(row['geometry'])
    closest_geom = list(tmp_gdf.sort_values('distance')['geometry'])[1]
    # I took 1 because index 0 would be the row itself
    snapped_geom = snap(row['geometry'], closest_geom, 0.5)
    s.set_value(index, 'geometry', snapped_geom)


    #new addition  
    o = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\ag_eus'
    s.to_file(o+ '\\new')
```

and the file is exactly the same with the first?

Answer (score 6):

`shapely.ops.snap(geom1, geom2, tolerance)` as in the docs, does the snapping between 2 objects of types geometry which means you have to find the 2 nearest objects in your data then snap them.

by combining `GeoDataFrame.distance(geom)` and `GeoDataFrame.sort_values(...)` you can get your nearest 2 objects.

```
for index, row in your_gdf.iterrows():
    tmp_gdf = your_gdf.copy()
    tmp_gdf['distance'] = tmp_gdf.distance(row['geometry'])
    closest_geom = list(tmp_gdf.sort_values('distance')['geometry'])[1]
    # I took 1 because index 0 would be the row itself
    snapped_geom = snap(row['geometry'], closest_geom, your_tolerance)
    your_gdf.loc[index, 'geometry'] = snapped_geom
```

Keep in mind that `snap` does not create vertices where there aren't any, it only moves vertices located within the tolerance.