# Extend the contours of the polygon into a polygon

Tags: python, geopandas, snapping, fiona, multi-polygon

I would like to be able to extend the vertices of one polygon to the edge of another polygon, how does the snapping between poligons using python.

The photo shows a representation of my problem.

[image]

I would like the orange polygon snap the red contour (the other polygon), as in the photo below.

[image]

I am using fiona as shown in this example ([How to do snapping in Geopandas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290092/how-to-do-snapping-in-geopandas)),  but I couldn't get the result.

```
from shapely.ops import snap
import geopandas as gpd

border_shp = gpd.read_file(...)
multipolygon = gpd.read_file(...)

for index, row in multipolygon.iterrows():
    closest_geom = list(border_shp ['geometry'])[1]
    snapped_geom = gpd.GeoDataFrame(snap(row['geometry'], closest_geom, 8))
```

Comment: what if `buffer > clip` ?

Comment: I tried it but it also affects the polygons inside the polygon I am trying to extend, do you know any way around this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have one dataframe or two?

Comment: I have two dataframe multipolygon

Comment: Can't you set the entire geometry of the orange feature to be the geometry of the red feature? Where do you *not* want the orange feature to relate to the red feature? Only where it is near already? Like a "snap" operation? Can you make a better example showing full polygons?

Comment: I updated my question, inserting the image of the final result, I tried with the snap function of shapely but I could not reach my goal. I would like to use python to solve this problem.