# Implementing undershoot correction in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, snapping

I am trying to implement an undershoot fixer using GeoPandas and Shapely like the solution from [Snapping in Geopandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290092)

My other thought is that it might reasonable to identify and extend the undershot segments so that the line geometries extend that way....
My sample geodataframe has 2 linestrings. I would like to have OBJECTID 2248 snapped to 2374. I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly.

Sample data - dfSamp:
`OBJECTID = [2248, 2374]`

`geometry = [<LINESTRING Z (-80.477 35.667 0, -80.476 35.667 0, -80.476 35.667 0)>, <LINESTRING Z (-80.476 35.667 0, -80.476 35.667 0, -80.478 35.667 0)>]`

Code I've tried from [Snapping in Geopandas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/290092) returns a results very similar to the original formatted sample data:

```
import geopandas as gpd  
from shapely.ops import snap  
tolerance = 0.0001

for index, row in dfSamp.iterrows():
    tmp_gdf = dfSamp.copy()
    tmp_gdf['distance'] = tmp_gdf.distance(row['geometry'])
    closest_geom = list(tmp_gdf.sort_values('distance')['geometry'])[2]
    snapped_geom = snap(row['geometry'], closest_geom, tolerance)
    dfSamp.loc[index, 'geometry'] = snapped_geom
```